Is it a good idea to use time as primary key component?
I have a log/audit table which the only index I will ever use is time window.
Is it a good idea to PRIMARY KEY it as:
CREATE TABLE events (
    created TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()
    ,id int DEFAULT AUTO_INCREMENT
    ...
); CONSTRAINT events_pk PRIMARY KEY (created, id);

This is not about using only TIMESTAMP as primary key, but a composable primary key which the first component is a TIMESTAMP.
I'm considering this for performance/storage reasons. Fetching is not my main concern, besides being able to fetch by a time-window. The rest of my schema uses the pattern
CREATE TABLE some_application_data (
    id UUID DEFAULT gen_random_uuid() PRIMARY KEY
    ,created TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()
    ...
);
create index xxx on some_application_data (created);

Is the first option an improvement? i did see smaller sizes on the files, but not by much, on my synthetic benchmark. Maybe if there was a more granular time type?
Or is UUID in practice a granular enough time field in the end? I could probably drop the timestamp field if it's ergonomic enough to search between two known timestamps using UUIDs, but I can't see how besides attaching a TIMESTAMP to them and then picking the begin/end UUID by their timestamps... alas, if i'm using timestamp indexes than i'm back to the second option in practice.

Your id is already the primary key, so adding created to it is redundant. It's unclear what you're trying to achieve by that.

@mustaccio i want to have an index where i can use WHERE created < "somedate" AND created > "anotherdate", without having yet another time based index.

@mustaccio continuing the explanation from the comment above...  my main idea was to have created as PK, but its not unique in under a milisecond, so i added id as int, which is not as big as UUID.

I can only repeat what I said earlier, based on the scant details you have provided about your data model: if you think you need a primary key, and you (rightfully) realise the timestamp isn't one, use ther auto-generated id as the primary key, there's no need to tag the timestamp to it.

I do want a timestamp primary key. but a timestamp is not possible as primary key alone.
